# MySQL Download Question

Tags: mysql

I want to download MySQL and use it on CentOS. But I found the downloading selection menu on the MySQL website is confusing. Which one should I choose? See the attached image.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use yum instead! :)

Comment: @DTest RHEL often ships [with stable (ie old) versions](http://server.billhamilton.com:84/wp/mysql/installing-mysql-5-5-11-on-rhel6-in-4-steps/) - I'm guessing Yousui wants 5.5 (but then perhaps CentOS is not the best distro, but that is another discussion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first looks like it is for RHEL5 and the second for RHEL6 (and clones) - judging by the filenames for the downloads:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: The Linux Gurus at my employer's web hosting company won't support RHEL6 just yet. Thank you, Jack, for bringing this to my attention. I didn't know MySQL RHEL6 binaries were out. I need to keep tabs on this one. +1 !!!